# How to execute a db2 query with a where condition using runqry command in CL/400

Tags: db2, rpgle

I was trying to execute a IBM DB2 query using runqry command of CLLE, but was unable to do it as it contained a where condition and I was unable to define a host variable in the runqry command. Can this be done by using the runqry command without using qryslt.

Please help me out.

Comment: Actually looks like this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RUNQRY` does not support variables.

You can define variables in the Query/400 query, but you must use the `Start Query Management Query (STRQMQRY)` command to run the query.

Be sure to specify:

```
Allow information from QRYDFN  . ALWQRYDFN  *YES`
```

Here's an [IBM document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010660) that shows how to do it.

> ```
>                         Select Records                                      
>    Type comparisons, press Enter.  Specify OR to start each new group.     
>      Tests: EQ, NE, LE, GE, LT, GT, RANGE, LIST, LIKE, IS, ISNOT...        
>
>    AND/OR  Field      Test    Value (Field, Number, 'Characters', or ...)  
>           GLCOMP     EQ      :COMPANY                                      
>    AND    GLBRAN     EQ      :BRANCH                                       
>    AND    GLACC      EQ      :ACCOUNT                                       
>   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

```
STRQMQRY QMQRY(library/qry-name) ALWQRYDFN(*YES) +
QMFORM(*QMQRY) SETVAR((COMPANY 1) (BRANCH 1) (ACCOUNT 12000))
```

Comment: You can also use & to denote a variable in qmqry but this would be for actual qmqry created with CRTQMQRY.